# Large file and OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, large-files

I’m new to C# and my boss wants me to investigate an `OutOfMemory` exception. The code that throws the exception is below specifically the first line if the file is large (>50MB):

```
     byte[] fileBytes = ws.getFile(f.FileId, f.Version); // This line gets the file from a webservice.
     File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(folder, f.FileId.ToString("0")), fileBytes);
```

I’ve read somewhere that using `byte[]` is not a good idea for large files.
can some help please ?

Comment: What is the task? Do you really need to read the whole file into memory?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, do not read everything into memory at once. This is what streams are used for. Copy 1 chunk at a time. There is not much else that anyone can offer unless you share the code inside method `ws.getFile`

Comment: Hi Zerkms, The task is to read  files form a CMS (case360 which exposes the getFile service to allow other apps to read the files from) then convert/ merge the files into a new PDF file and store it into the CMS. I agree loading large files into memory is not a good idea, so can you expand on stream/chunk please ?

Comment: Do you have other methods available from the web service instead of `getFile()`?  Perhaps one that returns a `Stream`? Also, returning a 50 Mb file as a byte array is definitely not a good idea, but it hardly explains the OOM, unless you call this multiple times and fragment the LOH as a consequence, maybe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your code is downloading the entire file and sticking it on the heap, then writing to a file locally.

To avoid the `OutOfMemoryException`, you will want to write to the disk as you go instead of waiting until the end. You can achieve this by getting the file from the webservice as a stream, opening a new file stream for writing and copying the contents over.

Comment: Thanks Scarl3tt, Can you point me to any sample code as that would save lots of hassles for a new C# starter?

Comment: Its easy to Google

Comment: @Greg - As Nidhin says, there are a lot of resources that will help you in getting a file from a web resource as a stream and saving a stream to a file. Without details on the implementation of your getFile method, there's not much point in writing any sample code here. If you provide that implementation, I can probably help a bit more.